# Removing frequency list from braces to list items downwards

Tags: python, list, for-loop, frequency

I have been trying to solve a task that requires me to produce a programme to determine the frequency of letters in a string.

I produced something that almost met the requirements of the task, but not quite. The final element was to list the letters of the alphabet and how often each letter appears in the string in this format:

```
A: 10
B: 2
C : 1
... etc.
```

My solution got me to this point:

```
{'a': 10, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 2, 'e': 2, 'f': 2, 'g': 0, 'h': 4, 'i': 6, 'j': 0, 'k': 0, 'l': 0, 'm': 2, 'n': 7, 'o': 9, 'p': 0, 'q': 0, 'r': 2, 's': 0, 't': 10, 'u': 5, 'v': 2, 'w': 2, 'x': 0, 'y': 2, 'z': 0}`
```

but I have not been able to work out how to remove this list from the braces and display them as above.

Here is my code:

```
message = "You can have data without information, but you cannot have information without data."
alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q",     "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
frequency = { "a": 0, "b": 0, "c": 0, "d": 0, "e": 0, "f": 0, "g": 0, "h": 0, "i": 0, "j": 0,    "k": 0, "l": 0, "m": 0, "n": 0, "o": 0, "p": 0, "q": 0, "r": 0, "s": 0, "t": 0, "u": 0, "v": 0, "w": 0, "x": 0, "y": 0, "z": 0 }

for i in alphabet:
    for j in message.lower():
        if i == j:
            frequency[i] += 1
print(frequency)
```

which produces this:

```
{'a': 10, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 2, 'e': 2, 'f': 2, 'g': 0, 'h': 4, 'i': 6, 'j': 0, 'k': 0, 'l': 0, 'm': 2, 'n': 7, 'o': 9, 'p': 0, 'q': 0, 'r': 2, 's': 0, 't': 10, 'u': 5, 'v': 2, 'w': 2, 'x': 0, 'y': 2, 'z': 0}
```

Can anybody help me understand how to convert these results to this:

```
a: 10
b: 1
c: 2
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This code counts how many times each `letter` of the `alphabet` appears in a given string and displays the results in the format ***`letter` : `number of occurrences`***

```py
message = "You can have data without information, but you cannot have information without data."
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"  
frequency = {char: 0 for char in alphabet}
for char in message.lower():
    if char in frequency:
        frequency[char] += 1
for char in alphabet:
    print(f"{char}: {frequency[char]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Its actually supper easy just use the items method of the dictionary that returns key-value pairs tuple.

```
alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
frequency = {letter: 0 for letter in alphabet} # you can use for clause comprehension to initialize the letters. 

message = message.lower()

for char in message:
    if char in frequency:
        frequency[char] += 1

for letter, count in frequency.items():  # use items method then unpack the tuple.
    print(f"{letter.upper()}: {count}")
```

Comment: You added this line to no avail `message = message.lower()` you can using this `for char in message.lower():`

Comment: if you want **one line solution** here you go!                                                      `from collections import Counter
import re
message = "You can have data without information, but you cannot have information without data."
print({ **{ chr(l): 0 for l in range(ord('A'), ord('Z') + 1)}, **Counter(re.sub(r'[^A-Z]', '', message.upper()))})`

Answer (score 0):

As with so many similar challenges, there are multiple ways to achieve your objective.

You should probably use the Counter class from the *collections* module thus:

```
from collections import Counter

message = "You can have data without information, but you cannot have information without data."
alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

counter = Counter(message.upper())

for c in alphabet:
    print(f"{c}: {counter.get(c, 0)}")
```

**Output:**

```
A: 10
B: 1
C: 2
D: 2
E: 2
F: 2
G: 0
H: 4
I: 6
J: 0
K: 0
L: 0
M: 2
N: 7
O: 9
P: 0
Q: 0
R: 2
S: 0
T: 10
U: 5
V: 2
W: 2
X: 0
Y: 2
Z: 0
```

Comment: The code you provided is incomplete; you must first define the `Counter`.

Comment: @XMehdi01 Thank you for your invaluable advice. However, I'm not inclined to *define* Counter. I prefer to import it instead

Comment: Yes, but the code you provided does not work because `Counter` is not defined

Comment: @XMehdi01 You may want to review your most recent comment

Comment: Yes, but you modified your code 

Comment: @XMehdi01 Am I not supposed to do that?

Comment: No, you have the right